# How to dynamically call accessor methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Regardless of whether it's good practice or not, how can I dynamically call accessor methods in Ruby?

Here's an example class:

```
class Test_Class
  attr_accessor :a, :b
end
```

I can use the Object.send method to read the variable...

```
instance.a = "value"
puts( instance.send( "a" ) )
# => value
```

But I'm having a hard time trying to write to it. These throw "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)"

```
instance.send("a", "value")
```

and

```
instance.method("a").call("value")
```

Please help me StackOverflow!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I am not a ruby expert, but I think that you could do:

```
instance.send("a=", "value")
```

Comment: Works, great! I guess the equal sign is part of the method name?

Comment: Yes, the equals sign in the conventional way to define setter methods in Ruby.

I would use a symbol rather than a string though. `instance.send(:a=, "value")`

Comment: Yep. attr_accessor makes two methods:

def v; @v; end

and 

def v=(value); @v=value; end

Comment: @Angela Will it work if value is boolean, I used for true/false it is setting when value is true, but not setting when value is false(all true and false mentioned as boolean)

Comment: the missing = of course!

Answer (score 11):

You can also directly access instance variables of an object using `instance_variable_*` functions:

```
instance = Test_Class.new                 # => #<Test_Class:0x12b3b84>

# instance variables are lazily created after first use of setter,
# so for now instance variables list is empty:
instance.instance_variables                # => []

instance.instance_variable_set(:@a, 123)   # => 123
instance.a                                 # => 123
instance.instance_variables                # => ["@a"]
instance.instance_variable_get("@a")       # => 123
```