# Ruby String to method name Error: undefined method `call=' for #<Method:0xa396aac> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have to dynamically call a list of methods on an object obj.
I am trying to instantiate a method object and then call it.

method_name (a string) is a name of a method which can be called on object obj.

```
meth=obj.method(method_name) #method_name is a string
meth.call = mod
```

I am getting the following error:

*undefined method `call=' for # (NoMethodError)*

I am using Sequel ORM and have to save model associations dynamically. 
If I directly call method_name (when method_name is not a string) the following is working

```
obj.method_name = mod #working
```

However, when method_name is a string, the following is giving a syntax error:

```
obj.send(method_name) = mod #not working
```

*syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end*

So I am not able to call the methods from their name in string form using any of the above ways.

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621176/how-to-dynamically-call-accessor-methods-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method named `method_name` takes the `mod` parameter try:

```
obj.send(method_name, mod)
```

If you are assigning something, then `method_name` should end with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for `call` is

```
call(args, ...)
```

[[ref](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-call)]

(Don't put `=` after call, just list the arguemnts separated by commas)

Also [Ingenu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630654/ingenu) method, is also a good way (probably better) of doing similar thing.